# can we override methods using IF else conditions in Java

Tags: java, overriding

I am trying to override the methods using a method in which I am using if-else condition. Is it possible in Java to override the methods using method with conditions?

Comment: Much better would be to show us the code of what exactly you're trying. Otherwise, your question is really unclear and only shows your lack of understanding the overriding concept.

Answer (score 3):

You can't override methods using an `if` statement - `if`s can only live inside blocks (such as methods), so you either do or don't override a method.

However, you can conditionally invoke the super method inside the overriding method:

```
@Override void yourMethod() {
  if (someCondition) {
    super.yourMethod();
  } else {
    // Do something else.
  }
}
```